# Word for hope-instilling?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What's a good word for hope instilling, as in "it is (hope instilling) to see that the first thing we teach our children is to say hello"..

Comment: You have a few answers to get your started, but we're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 6):

Inspiring, inspirational, and uplifting.

Answer (score 5):

[*Enheartening*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Enheartening) sounds like a good option to me.

Comment: Or just plain *heartening*, which I'd have thought is more common.

Answer (score 2):

I like [propitious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/propitious) - *indicative of favor; auspicious*

Comment: This is a nice one. But my sentence would require more context with that word, no? How could I use that in my sentence?

Comment: @mohabitar: I think the only context required for your sentence to make *propitious* suitable is that it should be in the general context of a conversation touching on favourable/unfavourable aspects of children's upbringing, and their possible futures. But you're right that it does need some context. Whereas with *heartening*, you could just come out with your sentence in isolation - as a simple observation, not necessarily in the context of any ongoing conversation at all.

Answer (score 1):

*Encouraging* might be the word you're looking for. (Other options include *promising* and, in some cases, *auspicious*.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this hasn't been suggested yet, but how about ***hopeful***?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than find a word that means "hope instilling," you might consider just rewriting your sentence to say what you want:

> It *instills hope* to see that the first thing we teach our children is to say hello.